# Answering Questions with Incomplete Phrases

Tags: грамматика

When you are asked a question like "Откуда вы?", and you wanted to answer with a single word, would you say "Россия" or "России"?

Comment: (Mention that asking a russian where is he from may be thought to mean "you're not supposed to be here", unless context gives no chance to interpret it this way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use both, but the second noun should be used with its preposition **из России** and it sounds **more correct**. But speaking to foreigners I would choose *Россия*.

Comment: Similarly, if someone asks, say, what you are going to buy at a shop, would you answer in nominative or accusative (like книга vs книгу)?

Comment: Only accusative ( книгу).

Answer (score 8):

*Из России* is the proper answer. *России* would be definitely a **mistake**: you can't use the required case with dropped preposition here. *Россия* из possible but not perfect: similar simplified, low colloquial answers sometimes even sound impolite.